# Should I update sources.list.d jessie->stretch?

Tags: debian, upgrade

I am upgrading from jessie to stretch, I understood that I have to replace `jessie` by `stretch` in the `sources.list` but what about those in `sources.list.d/`
I have these sources under `sources.list.d/`:

`mysql.list`:

```
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ jessie mysql-apt-config 
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ jessie mysql-5.6 
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ jessie mysql-tools
deb-src http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ jessie mysql-5.6
```

`nodesource.list`:

```
deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x jessie main
deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x jessie main
```

`php.list` (for some reason this was already on stretch):

```
deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ stretch main
```

Comment: you have no default entries in your source.list. https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Using Debian jessie is soon EOL.  https://wiki.debian.org/LTS

Comment: Thanks nobody. I do have entries in my sources.list, I just didn't show them here since I was only wondering about the other sources from the folder sources.list.d

Answer (score 1):

Yes, After upgrading to debian `stretch`, you need to edit the 3rd party repository by replacing the `jessie` codename with `stretch` under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` .

```
sudo sed -i 's/jessie/stretch/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/{nodesource,mysql}.list
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```